# Designing a TextCtrl which fills up the entire frame

Tags: perl, wxperl

I am programming with wxPerl and I was wondering how you would design it so that a textctrl, or really any component, would fill up the entire frame and resize with the window?

So far my attempts at researching this problem have led me to believe that potentially using the wxBoxSizer is the way to go but documentation for wxPerl is a little scarce..

Thank you all for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the [wxWidgets API](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/) is excellent and very comprehensive. `wxPerl` exposes most of the API in a stratightforward manner.

If a `Wx::Frame` object has only a single child window, the default size event handler automatically resizes the child to fill the frame.

If you have a more complex requirement then you can overload the handler or, as you say, write a sizer.