# wxPerl: add component which resizes automatically when parent frame gets resized

Tags: perl, fill, expand, wxperl

I am relatively new to Perl and I am using `wxPerl` to create a GUI application. Now, I want to add a `Panel` into a `Frame`, possibly using a `sizer` so that the panel resizes automatically as the frame gets resized.

So here's what I got:

(1) I have to use a `BoxSizer`, which stretch components in one direction.

(2) I have to pass parameters in the `Add` subroutines to stretch components in another direction.

I wrote the following code:

```
package Main;
use Wx;
use parent 'Wx::App';

sub OnInit {
    my $frame = Wx::Frame->new(undef, -1, "SimpleCalc ".$Information::VERSION_NO, [-1,-1], [-1,-1]);
    my $centerPanel = Wx::Panel->new($frame, -1, [-1,-1], [-1,-1]);
    #set red background
    $centerPanel->SetBackgroundColour(Wx::Colour->new(255,0,0));
    my $frameSizer = Wx::BoxSizer->new(wxHORIZONTAL);
    $frameSizer->Add($centerPanel, 1, 0, 0);
    $frame->SetSizer($frameSizer);
    $frame->Center();
    $frame->Show(1);
    return 1;
}

my $app = Main->new;
$app->MainLoop;
```

The unwanted result:

[image: unstretched]

What I want is to stretch the red panel in both (horizontal and vertical) direction, or in short, I want something similar to `BorderLayout` in `Java`.

According to some online tutorials, I tried to replace `$frameSizer->Add($centerPanel, 1, 0, 0);` with 
`$frameSizer->Add($centerPanel, 1, wxEXPAND, 0);`, but the script doesn't run. An error occurs saying that it is unable to resolve overload for Wx::Sizer::Add(Wx::Panel, number, scalar, number). I also tried `$frameSizer->Add($centerPanel, 1, 0, 0, wxEXPAND);`, but the frame obtained is exactly the same as the frame in the image.

Is it possible to have something similar to Java's `BorderLayout` in `wxPerl`? Thanks in advance.

P.S. I know there is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271412/designing-a-textctrl-which-fills-up-the-entire-frame), but there are no concrete answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

In case you weren't aware, the default sizer for any child window will make it fill its available space, so to achieve the effect you're asking for all you need is this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Information;

our $VERSION_NO = 9.99;


package Main;
use Wx qw/ :colour /;
use parent 'Wx::App';

sub OnInit {

  my $frame = Wx::Frame->new(undef, -1, "SimpleCalc $Information::VERSION_NO");

  my $centerPanel = Wx::Panel->new($frame);
  $centerPanel->SetBackgroundColour(wxRED);

  $frame->Center;
  $frame->Show;

  return 1;
}

my $app = Main->new;
$app->MainLoop;
```

---

**Original**

It would have helped you a *lot* if you had `use strict` and `use warnings` in place! I and several others have to endlessly encourage people to do that but it seems sometimes that the message will never get across. Please try to make a habit of adding these statements to the top of every Perl program you write, and help us to spread the word

There are two things preventing your program from working

- The value `wxHORIZONTAL` is undefined because you haven't imported it from `Wx`, so you are passing a value of zero to `Wx::BoxSizer->new` without any warning being raised
- You have used a value of zero for the third parameter to `$frameSizer->Add`, which prevents the panel from expanding transversly to the direction of the sizer. You need `wxEXPAND` in there to enable it, and you will also need to import the value of that constant of course

Here's a rewrite of your code that fixes these problems, and also takes advantage of the defaults that will be used for missing parameters. I've also used `wxRED` instead of creating a new `Wx::Colour` object. I had to set a value for `$Information::VERSION_NO` too

This code works as you expected

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Information;

our $VERSION_NO = 9.99;


package Main;

use Wx qw/ :sizer :colour /;
use parent 'Wx::App';

sub OnInit {
    my $frame = Wx::Frame->new(undef, -1, "SimpleCalc $Information::VERSION_NO");

    my $centerPanel = Wx::Panel->new($frame);
    $centerPanel->SetBackgroundColour(wxRED);

    my $frameSizer = Wx::BoxSizer->new(wxHORIZONTAL);
    $frameSizer->Add($centerPanel, 1, wxEXPAND);
    $frame->SetSizer($frameSizer);

    $frame->Center;
    $frame->Show;

    return 1;
}

my $app = Main->new;
$app->MainLoop;
```

**output**

[Fixed WxWidgets screen http://bit.ly/1JNrrEL](http://bit.ly/1JNrrEL)

Comment: Thanks! One more thing to ask: is there any comprehensive documentation which tells where the variables are defined?

Comment: @tony200910041: Do you mean the *constants*, like `wxHORIZONTAL`? They're defined in the wxWidgets library. They're pulled into the `Wx` module by the code in `Constants.xs` from various C header files in the wxWidgets include directory. If you want documentation on how to use them then the best place is the [*wxWidgets documentation*](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/index.html)